# sendmail gives empty recipients in email

Tags: email, scripts, sendmail

Im using a script that takes backup and sends status email using sendmail but the emails its sending comes with the to tag empty here is an image of it

Here is the part of the script

```
    #Email Settings
    Message_Success="Backup generated successfully"
    Message_Failure="Problem occured while generating Backup"

    Subject="Backup Status Mail"
    Sender_Name=Backup
    Recipients="tarun@gmail.com"

echo "Subject:$Subject\n\n$Message_Failure" | sendmail -F $Sender_Name $Recipients

echo "Subject:$Subject\n\n$Message_Success" | sendmail -F $Sender_Name $Recipients
```

can it be solved so that I can see who has recieved emails. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put the recipients in the message and use sendmail's `-t` flag:

```
#Email Settings
Message_Success="Database Backup generated successfully"
Message_Failure="Problem occured while generating Database Backup please verify"
Subject="Database Backup Status Mail"
Sender_Name=DatabaseBackup
Recipients="tarun@gmail.com,user1@gmail.com"

sendmail -F $Sender_Name -it <<END_MESSAGE
To: $Recipients
Subject: $Subject

$Message_Success
END_MESSAGE
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works?

Comment: Did you look at the sendmail man page?

Comment: The point of StackExchange is not to refer people to man pages!

Comment: The point of StackExchange is to ask questions and get answers. The best answer to your question resides in the sendmail man page.

Comment: To save everyone the trouble: `-t Extract recipients from message headers.`

Comment: It's against the rules to simply refer people to off-network sources, though. Also, you should update your answer with that extra detail, not add it as a comment, to help ensure users can find it easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100978/discussion-between-deed02392-and-glenn-jackman).